# ST7735 driver IC connection with TFT DISPLAY

Tags: pcb, schematics, esp32, tft, character-lcd

I am a noob to electronics and thinking of using this 128x160 1.8 inch Color TFT LCD Display with ST7735 Controller SPI in my project. So, does the TFT Display come with a pre-programmed ST7735 Controller or do we have to program the Controller ourselves from designing the schematic to driver firmware? Or it comes with direct plug-and-play like pre-connected and we have to use the SPI pins like SDA, SCL, CLK, VCC, and GND of MCU to make the connection to the Display.

https://www.buydisplay.com/128x160-1-8-inch-color-tft-lcd-display-with-st7735-controller-spi

This is the link to the display I want to you for my project.

If we have to make the schematic for the ST7735 driver IC connection with TFT DISPLAY can you help me? in finding the proper resource for that also. I am using ESP32-S3 MCU to display the live video feed from the camera to TFT Display.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ST7735 does not contain a CPU and thus does not run any firmware so you don't need to develop firmware or upload it into ST7735.

Comment: Thank for the help! Tried the display and it’s good.

Comment: @SukhdarshanVinayak If the answer was correct then accept it as the correct answer.